# Git doesn't use credentials from git-credentials-store file

Tags: git, continuous-integration, credentials, rust-cargo

I'm trying to compile some Rust code inside CI, which depends on another private git repository.
Since it's in CI I cannot enter credentials manually, so I'm trying to use git-credentials-store. This is what I did in my attempt to set up git-credentials-store:

```
echo 'https://username:password@placeholder.com/repo.git' > git-credentials
git config credentials.helper 'store --file git-credentials'`
```

To build the project, it has to fetch from that private git repo.
When it tries to build, it fails, saying that this is the command it tried:

```
git fetch --tags --force --update-head-ok 'https://placeholder.com/git/repo.git' 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

And this is the error message:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://placeholder.com': No such device or address
```

Would this indicate that it asks for username in stdin? I expected that the command would use the username and password from the git-credentials file.

Comment: Your example uses `placeholder.eu` in one place and `placeholder.com` in others.  I assume this is an oversight.

Comment: Yes thanks, corrected

Answer (score 1):

In general, the URL put in the credential file should not contain a path component.  The `git credential-store` manual page gives this format:

```
https://user:pass@example.com
```

Git doesn't usually consider the path component at all when looking up credentials unless `credential.useHTTPPath` is set.  If you set a path component, you're likely not going to match what Git requests in this case, which is a generic set of credentials for the domain in question.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I get the same error with that syntax. That is, `echo 'https://username:password@placeholder.com' > git-credentials`

Comment: Then either your password has special characters which must be encoded, or your credentials are not correct.  You may also want to use `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` to `0` to avoid the terminal prompt and get a better error message.

Comment: Thanks,  I it seems like this is the case. In what way does it have to be encoded?

Comment: The password has to be URI encoded.  In general, if it contains a character that is not a letter, number, `-`, or `_`, the best thing to do is to write those byte values as `%` followed by two hex characters representing its ASCII (or UTF-8) byte value.  So an `=` would be `%3D` and a `@` would be `%40`, for example.